# Controller check requirements to process action

Tags: php, symfony, lifecycle

I'm trying to figure out if there is **possibility to check requirements** before processing controller action. In Nette there are methods like `checkRequirements`, `onStartup`, `beforeRender` where I can check this.

I have api resource `album/{albumId}/song/` and I would like to check if album with given `id` exists every time any action on my **SongController** is processed and **return 404 status code** if not.

So far I have found [this article in Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) where I found there are no methods like `preExecute` and `postExecute`. However I guess there is **bundle or something like that to add those methods**. I think it does not make sense to create new class to use it only in one controller.

Are there any other options to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) does that. It looks for a entity using the id supplied from the route and throws an exception, returning a 404 if it doesn't find anything.

```
// paramConverter requires that you type-hint a class, which is a best practice anyway :)
public function getArtist(\Appbundle\Entity\Song $song)
{
    //...
}
```